# How do I send data between the pages on my website

Tags: javascript

I'm not actually sure if this is a javascript-question, but here goes. 
I'm making an online store for my employer(small business that can't afford professional help) and I have a problem. 
When the user clicks a product category link on the front page that directs to the product page, I want data to be passed to the product page so it knows which products to get from the database. How do I do this?

Thanks :)

Comment: You need to provide more information about your case. In this case, backend technologies used, and some parts of your frontend code.

Answer (score 0):

it's called XmlHttpRequest or Ajax combine with authentication and authorization, familiar your self with those tech and term first then you will be ready to implement it